# How to create a control for css opacity in the Customizer

Tags: customization

I am super new to  working with the customizer built into WordPress.  I have been reading articles all day and picking up things.   I see with the customizer that we can create various types when it comes to creating add_control components.  For example, I see the following makes a date input field...

```
$wp_customize->add_control( 'custom_theme_css', array(
  'type' => 'date',
  'priority' => 10, // Within the section.
  'section' => 'colors', // Required, core or custom.
  'label' => __( 'Date' ),
  'description' => __( 'This is a date control with a red border.' ),
  'input_attrs' => array(
    'class' => 'my-custom-class-for-js',
    'style' => 'border: 1px solid #900',
    'placeholder' => __( 'mm/dd/yyyy' ),
  ),
  'active_callback' => 'is_front_page',
  'section' => 'custom_css',
));
```

I also see the following makes a textarea component...

```
  $wp_customize->add_control( 'custom_theme_css', array(
  'label' => __( 'Custom Theme CSS' ),
  'type' => 'textarea',
  'section' => 'custom_css',
  ));
```

...but how do we make one relating to a css opacity value? I want to do something like this within the color section of the customizer, that allows the background of the page to have an opacity adjustment.

```
  $wp_customize->add_control( 'custom_theme_css', array(
  'label' => __( 'Change Opacity' ),
  'type' => 'css',
  'opacity' => ''//some variable that gets user input for opacity value
  'section' => 'color',
   ));
```

What must I do to learn how to build this correctly?

**Update**

Below is a final result of my demo in adjusting a background opacity:

```
add_action( 'customize_register' , 'lesson01b_options' );

function lesson01b_options( $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'lesson01b_msection', array(
    'title' => __( 'Opacity Adjustments' ),
    'description' => __( 'Adjust the opacity this way background images show through' ),
    'panel' => '',
    'priority' => 39, //160 by default
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'theme_supports' => '',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'lesson01b_msetting', array(
    'type' => 'theme_mod', // or 'option'
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'theme_supports' => '',
    'default' => '',
    'transport' => 'refresh', // or postMessage
    'sanitize_callback' => '',
    'sanitize_js_callback' => '',
    ));

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'lesson01b_mcontrol', array(
    'label' => __( 'Opacity Control', 'lesson1b' ),
    'type' => 'text',
    'section' => 'lesson01b_msection',
    'settings' => 'lesson01b_msetting',
    ));
}

add_action( 'wp_head' , 'lesson01b_get_setting' );

function lesson01b_get_setting() {
    ?>
    <style type='text/css'>
    #page {
        opacity:<?php echo get_theme_mod('lesson01b_msetting') ?> ;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such value of `'type'` parameter in `add_control()` function. See the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_control).

What you can do is create a control e.x.:

```
$wp_customize->add_control(
   'my_control', 
    array(
        'label'    => __( 'Opacity Control', 'mytheme' ),
        'section'  => 'my_section',
        'settings' => 'my_setting',
        'type'     => 'text',
    )
);
```

And then in file which you have `<head>` tag in (I suppose it's **header.php** file) add following code:

```
<head>
  <style>
    *{
      opacity: <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'my_control', '0' ); ?>
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Now when you change value of the control, your opacity will change too and you should see the result. **Note** that value of your theme option must be in range from 0 to 1 so you have keep it in mind. I hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Sebastian you rock. I will reproduce this on Monday to confirm.  Have a great weekend!

Comment: Great answer! I'd like to add onto this with some [documentation from the Developers Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/#controls). There are HTML5 `number` and `range` types which allow you to define a min and max number along with `step` incrementation which you could set at `0.1`. Using something like this will make it easier to sanitize and process.

Comment: Sebastian thanks again, but I am still having an issue.  no matter what I do, the get_theme_mod resorts to its default value of 0.9 only. It never changes.  any advice based on my updated code above? thanks

Comment: Found mistakes on my end.  I was referencing the control, when I suppose to reference the settings to display my opacity adjustments.  Thanks again for sparking the fire and helping me think through this.